# Is it possible to use powershell command to enable file access option in windows settings?

Tags: powershell, uwp

I'm developing a business UWP app for sideloading. The app will read and write to the file which is out of the App domain. For example, the file path is `c:\\folder1\\1.txt`

I followed the document [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#capabilities-for-accessing-other-locations), and add the capability `broadFileSystemAccess`. After the app is deployed on my customers' machines, I need to let my customers to go to the `Settings > Privacy > File system` and enable the file access option for my app at first, then the app will work well.

My customers do not want to do this step (`enable file access option`) manually. They want an automatic way to do it. Is it possible to use powershell to achieve this target? or other better ways?

Comment: You could use the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to investigate which registry changes occur, when you make this change manually. After that, you can implement the registry changes in a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Registry `[Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\broadFileSystemAccess]`.

If you have installed your application, you can see your app's `package family name`.

Modify the `Value Data` to `Allow`.

You can use [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.3#example-2-create-a-registry-entry-and-value) to set the registry.

```
 Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\broadFileSystemAccess\[your package family name]" -Name "Value" -Value "Allow"
```

[image]